# How can I set percentage format on a column in Dash DataTable?

Tags: python, datatables, plotly-dash

I am working with Python Dash, and I am using the DataTable to display some information from a certain dataset. This dataset only has two columns corresponding to education rates. The rate is a decimal number that represents a percentage; however, I have tried to apply the percentage format to the columns without success. This is how things are set up:

```
percentage=FormatTemplate.percentage(2)

dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='educ-table',
                    columns=[{'name':i, 'id':i, 'type':'numeric', 'format':percentage } for i in df_edu[(df_edu['County']==df_edu['County'].unique()[0]) &(df_edu['Age']==df_edu['Age'].unique()[0])&(df_edu['Year']==df_edu['Year'].unique()[0])][['Educational Attainment', 'Percentage']].columns],
                    data=df_edu[(df_edu['County']==df_edu['County'].unique()[0]) &(df_edu['Age']==df_edu['Age'].unique()[0])&(df_edu['Year']==df_edu['Year'].unique()[0])][['Educational Attainment', 'Percentage']].to_dict('records'),
                    editable=True,
                    sort_action='native',
                    sort_mode='multi',
                    row_selectable=False,
                    row_deletable=False,
                    selected_columns=[],
                    selected_rows=[],
                    page_size=10,
                    style_cell={'font-family':'Arial', 'textAlign':'center'},
                    style_header={'font-family':'Arial'}
                )
```

When I load the app, I see the column apply the percentage format for a mere second, then it goes back to decimal. This is a screenshot of the table:
[image: DataTable]

Comment: I added an answer to your question. I hope it helps but let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not super helpful because it is long and confusing. More importantly, we do not know the `dtype` of the percentage column in your DataFrame.

Assuming you are looking at the Number Formatting page in Dash documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/data-formatting) and replicating the code example, I suspect the data type of your column is `string` (i.e., `object`), not `float` as it should be. You can check this with the following code:

```
df.dtypes
```

If you see the column's dtype as `object`, you can recast the data as `float` with the following snippet before passing your data to the DataTable:

```
df["Percentage"] = df["Percentage"].astype(float)
```